# how is the connection between Rancher and a container established?

Tags: rancher

I am not very familiar with kubernetes yet.

I have a small k8s cluster in a VM and rancher in the cloud. Both are connected to each other. I deployed a database on the k8s cluster via the rancher UI.

Then I can connect directly to the container of the database via the shell-window in the Rancher UI. How is the secure connection guaranteed here? Are these two TLS connections - one from the rancher backend to the cattle cluster agent and then again from the cattle cluster agent to the database container?

Do you know an article that describes this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/rancher/dashboard/blob/master/components/nav/WindowManager/KubectlShell.vue

It uses a websocket connection to connect to the cluster in question.